# Arduino C not going into loop?

Tags: c, arduino

```
char* lastfeedbuffer[3];
void lastfeed_receive(){
  while(Serial.available() >= LASTFEED_LEN ){
    char c = Serial.read();
    if (c == LASTFEED_HEAD){
      for (int i = 0; i < LASTFEED_LEN - 1; i++){
        lastfeedbuffer[i] = Serial.read();
      } 
    }
  }
  Serial.println(lastfeedbuffer);
  if (lastfeedbuffer == "00"){
    Serial.println("asdf");
  }
}
```

I don't understand why the following code is not printing the `asdf`.  the `Serial.println(lastfeedbuffer)` prints `00`, which means it should go into the loop any ideas why it doesn't?

Comment: `lastfeedbuffer` and `"00"` are not of compatible types: the first is of type `array of 3 pointer to char`; the second is of type `array of char`. Increase the warning level of your compiler and **MIND THE WARNINGS**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `strcmp(lastfeedbuffer, "00") == 0` - What you're currently doing is to compare two unrelated pointers.

Also, I believe you have `char lastfeedbuffer[3];` not `char* lastfeedbuffer[3];` in your actual code?